# Selenium webdriver - resolve multiple promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise

The code below works, except for that I don't want to just print out the results when resolved, I would like to be able to structure them in JSON format. 
I think for that, I need to wait for all promises to get resolved, but I don't know how!

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .build();

    driver.get('www.example.com');
    driver.sleep(2000);

    driver.findElements(By.css('.listing')).then(function(resWraps){
        for (var i=0; i<resWraps.length; i++) {
            resWraps[i].findElement(By.css('.title a')).getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function(title){
                console.log(title);
            });
            resWraps[i].findElement(By.css('.price')).getAttribute("innerHTML").then(function(price){
                console.log(price);
            });    
        }
    });
```

So, I get a list. Then I'd like to find multiple elements inside each element of the list. But I don't know how to wait for all promises to be resolved in order to make my final JSON array.

Comment: to wait for all Promises .... use ... `Promise.all`

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks, but it still fails randomly.. I'm not sure how to handle `Promise.all` inside a loop

Comment: or maybe it's because of the dynamic reordering of the items: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Answer (score 2):

Promise.all resolves an array so you need to push elements to an array and then pass that to Promise.all function. Something like:

```
const promiseArray = []
for (var i=0; i<resWraps.length; i++) {
   promiseArray.push(resWraps[i].findElement(By.css('.title a')).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
}

return Promise.all(promiseArray)
   .then(resolvedList){
 // do something with resolvedList
}
```

Not sure if this code will run but it's an example, if you look at the documentation for [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) then the argument that is passed to Promise.all has to be iterable.

Hope this helps